# Best way to identify product number using LUIS with Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, bots, azure-language-understanding

Im using LUIS Microsoft Bot Framework and Node.js to program a Bot.

If i ask my bot:
"Get me product WKJ UJK HYF"

What is the best way to identify the product identification "WKJ UJK HYF" and determining the intent?

i have tried using regexp but i can't get it right. And what if someone tries:
"Get me product WKJUJKHYF"

how can i cover these 2 scenarios in a good way?

i have tried using the regexp: "^[a-zA-Z\s]{9,12}$" but LUIS fails and thinks that only the 3 first letters are the product, and it also gives me an entity containing numbers (like "YHJ123455").

Comment: Did you train your LUIS modal..? I think you can get same intent by giving more training to your modal..

Comment: yes i did train him, several times and did not get the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be solved by providing more examples with different patterns to make the model flexible.
Examples:

- get me product ID
- show me ID
- price of ID
- etc...

Also you can provide some product IDs as a phrasal list feature to make LUIS familiar with their patterns.